# Bug em accordion jquery

Tags: jquery

Olá estou com um problema no meu jquery, parece que está tudo certo...

aqui code do jquery

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //Definimos que todas as tags dd terão display none
 $('dd').hide();
   // Ao clicar no link, executamos a funcao
 $('dt a').click(function(){
    // As tags dd's visíveis agora ficam com display: none
 $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
  //Apos, a funcao é transferida para seu pai, que procura o proximo irmao no codigo o tornando visivel
 $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
     return false;   
      });      
 });
 </script>
```

aqui meu code php

```
<h2><?php echo $modulo_atual["titulo_modulo"]; ?></h2>
                   <dl>
                       <?php
                          $capitulos =  consultar("capitulo","ativo_capitulo = 'S' and id_modulo = $id_modulo");
                          foreach ($capitulos as $capitulo) {
                              $id_capitulo = $capitulo['id_capitulo'];

                       ?>
                        <dt><a href=""><?php echo $capitulo["capitulo"]; ?></a></dt>
                           <dd>
                               <ul>
                               <?php
                                 $aulas = consultar("aula","id_capitulo = $id_capitulo and ativo_aula = 'S' and id_modulo = $id_modulo ");
                                 if ($aulas) {
                                      foreach ($aulas as $aula) {
                                          echo "<li><a href=index.php?link=2&a=$aula[id_aula]&m=$id_modulo&c=$id_capitulo>$aula[titulo_aula]</a></li>";
                                      }
                                 }
                               ?>


                               </ul>

                           </dd>
                          <?php } ?>                
                   </dl>
```

No meu sistema eu clico no módulo 01 e o accordion funciona perfeitamente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já nos próximos módulos o accordion não funciona 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Veja neste link como tem um meio muito mais simples de fazer accordion.
http://www.tidbits.com.br/como-fazer-accordion-simples-com-jquery-em-5-linhas-de-codigo